# ngFor* not returning data from REST endpoint in Angular 5

Tags: angular, rest, ngfor

So I am trying to use an ngFor* to pull REST data into my html but I am getting no data back. I'm not sure what is going on as it seems similar to the example I followed. I was trying to pull to place in a navbar some dropdowns, but since that is not working I simplified for now. Here is my ngFor*

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li *ngFor="let conference of conferenceList" class="list-group-item">
    <ul>{{conference.conferenceName}}</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Conference Service:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import {EventEmitter, Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Conference} from "./conference.model";

@Injectable()
export class ConferenceService {

   onConferenceAdded = new EventEmitter<Conference>();


   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

   }

   getConferences(): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get('/api/conference');
   }

}
```

My Conference-list component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Conference} from "../conference.model";
import {ConferenceService} from "../conference.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-conferences-list',
  templateUrl: './conferences-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./conferences-list.component.css']
})
export class ConferencesListComponent implements OnInit {

  conferenceList: Conference[] = [];

  constructor(private conferenceService: ConferenceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.conferenceService.getConferences()
      .subscribe(
        (conferences: any[]) => {
          this.conferenceList = conferences;
        },
        (error) => console.log(error)
      )
  }

}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have been looking into this for some time and can't seem to figure it out.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post what you get back from your http request?

Comment: Add the log statement inside of the `subscribe` method to see what you get from the server. For example: `console.dir(conferences); this.conferenceList = conferences;`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan that log does not appear in my console

Comment: @ebraun99 do you get any errors? Is your http request successful?

Comment: @LLai I solved the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect JSON, and not array from the service

(conferences: any[]) --> this typing could be wrong

use  `(conferences: any)` instead

Comment: you shouldn't have the return statement in there

Comment: Angular 5 HttpClient implements map automatically, is what I found. It's not even possible to manually implement it.

Comment: @ebraun99 the httpClient assumes your response is json unless told otherwise. so no need for parsing with `.json()`

Comment: Edited my answer, its probably the type and please console.log the output from the service to get a better idea

Comment: I should be able to place this inside the ngOnInit in conferenceListComponent correct? The log is not showing up. Maybe I am placing it in the incorrect spot.I put `console.log("Data:" + this.conferenceService.getConferences());` above the rest of my code in my ngOnInit and the log doesn't show up at all

Comment: You can first try if the call is happening in networks tab. Second, try logging as below ngOnInit() {
    this.conferenceService.getConferences()
      .subscribe(
        (conferences: any) => {console.log(conferences)
          this.conferenceList = conferences;
        },
        (error) => console.log(error)
      )
  }

Comment: I am getting a 404 error for not found. My application is going to port 4200 to look for the data even though i have it configured for 8080 with a proxy-conf.json file and set correctly in my package.json

Comment: Managed to fix it and get data back. Thanks for all the help was just missing a command when serving it back.